# Standard lightweight one-way hash functions for IoT devices

Tags: hash, one-way-function, lightweight

What are the standard lightweight one-way hash functions used in current Internet of Things devices?

I could find some proposal of hash functions in conference papers but I want to know the ones which are being currently used. I found no concrete answer while searching on internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One primitive that has gained a lot of traction in recent time is [BLAKE2s](https://blake2.net/), one of the SHA-3 runner ups, which is often prefered to the actual SHA-3 winner because of its performance.

Another option would be to use a [sponge construction](http://sponge.noekeon.org/) with a dedicated lightweight permutation function like [Quark](https://www.131002.net/quark/) or [Photon](https://sites.google.com/site/photonhashfunction/).

Comment: Just a bit more help. Do you know of any resource that compares Blake against Quark?

Comment: A nice overview about lightweight hashes can be found here: https://www.cryptolux.org/index.php/Lightweight_Hash_Functions Unfortunately, they do not feature blake2s.

Comment: Note that BLAKE2 _was not part of the SHA-3 competition_. It is a "successor" (?) of BLAKE which was part of the competition.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a study about different cryptographic methods in different IoT devices:

**[Midgar: Study of communications security among Smart Objects using a platform of heterogeneous devices for the Internet of Things](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313327898_Midgar_Study_of_communications_security_among_Smart_Objects_using_a_platform_of_heterogeneous_devices_for_the_Internet_of_Things)**

In this study, the authors (Sánchez-Arias, García, and García-Bustelo) explain the time that the different methods need to send messages and a comparison between the methods, about their current state and about the time that they needed.

> #### Abstract
>
> In last years, the Internet of Things has been a revolution in terms of applications and research. Currently, there are a great variety of nodes connected to each other to create different applications in areas, ranging from sport to business, inter alia. These applications compromise our private information about our bank accounts, health, and location. This makes us take safety measures to achieve a secure communication, where the interception of a message by a malicious user cannot compromise our privacy.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at ISO/IEC 29192 which is a standard for lightweight cryptography that specifies several techniques for block/stream ciphers, asymmetric techniques and hash functions.

Specifically, the fifth subsequent part [ISO/IEC 29192-5](https://www.iso.org/standard/67173.html) is about hash functions and specifies three such functions suitable for applications requiring lightweight cryptographic implementations: [PHOTON](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/609.pdf), [SPONGENT](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/697.pdf) and [Lesamnta-LW](http://fuee.u-fukui.ac.jp/~hirose/publication/e95-a_1_89.pdf).

Comment: Spongent is SLOOOOOW.